# How to update custom single user login system into multi user login system with laravel, Jquary-Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hello iam new to laravel and i have created a custom single user login system. Now i have to updated this
login page with custom multi Auth that will redirect the users based on their roles.
but i dont know how to redirect the authenticated users to different pages based on their roles?

I have 3 users-> admin user,doctor user and receptionist user
I have use laravel,Jquery-Ajax.

please help me to create multi user login page.

**login page**

```
@extends('layouts.index')

@section('title') {{'Login'}} @endsection
@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-item-center min-vh-100">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card shadow">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="text-center">System Login</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body p-5">
                    <div id="login_alert"></div>
                    <form method="POST" action="#" id="login_form">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="E-mail">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Password">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <a class="text-decoration-none" href="{{ url('/forgot_password')}}">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3 d-grid">
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-dark rounded-0" id="login-btn">
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center text-secondary">
                            <div>Don't Have an account? <a href="{{ url('/register')}}" class="text-decoration-none">Register Here</a></div>
                         
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection

@section('script')
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#login_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#login-btn").val('please wait...');
        $.ajax ({
        url:'{{ route('auth.login')}}',
        method: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            if(res.status == 400) {
            showError('email', res.messages.email);
            showError('password', res.messages.password);
            $("#login_btn").val('Login');
        } else if(res.status == 401) {
            $("#login_alert").html(showMessage('danger',res.messages));
            $("#login_btn").val('Login');
        }else {
            if(res.status == 200 && res.messages == 'success'){
                window.location = '{{ route('profile')}}';
            }

        }
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

**UserController.php**

```
//handle login user ajax 
    `public function loginUser(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:100',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|max:50'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 400,
                'messages' => $validator->getMessageBag()
            ]);
           }else{
              $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
              if($user){
                if(Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
                    $request->session()->put('loggedInUser',$user->id);
                    return response()->json([
                        'status' => 200,
                        'messages' => 'success'
                        
                    ]);
                } else{
                    return response()->json([
                        'status' => 401,
                        'messages' => 'E-mail or Password is incorrect!'
                    ]);
                }
              } else{
                    return response()->json([
                        'status' => 401,
                        'messages' => 'User not found!'
                ]);
              }
           }
    }

     //profile page
    public function profile(){
        return view('profile');
    }

    //logout method
    public function logout(){
        if(session()->has('loggedInUser')){
            session()->pull('loggedInUser');
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }
```

**kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareAliases = [

 'LoginCheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\LoginCheck::class,
    ];
```

**LoginCheck.php**-middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if(!session()->has('loggedInUser') && ($request->path() != '/login' && $request->path() !='/register')){
            return redirect('/login');
        }
        if(session()->has('loggedInUser') && ($request->path() == '/login' || $request->path() =='/register')){
            return back();
        }
        return $next($request)->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,must-revalidate')
        ->header('Pragma', 'no-cache')->header('Expires','Sat 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
```

Please help me to upadate the login form.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use laravel default auth guard for multiple authentication. checkout this blog, exact for your requirement : https://techvblogs.com/blog/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel-9

Comment: @Kavan Prajapati   Thank you very much for your help. But I want to develop a custom multiuser login system without any application. May I know whether this code can be updated or not?  Please help